# VBA in Excel: Controlling a Chart with Dynamic Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, charts, range

I have been working on an excel model with dynamic charts. Essentially a user should be able to change the periods charted on a diagram - so fairly simple. However, I keep having issues with making the VBA work as I intend (I do not get errors, but it does not behave as I would expect).
What I am attempting to do:

1. Set a dynamic legend (depending on how many items the user wants to chart) - the number of items is defined in Excel and is simply added to the number of rows in VBA.
2. Set a dynamic range (start and end depends on user input), however, it seems like I cannot define where the range containing data for plotting starts.

In my code below Excel seems to ignore the parameters in `Rng2`, i.e. it starts plotting from column 53 until column 77, instead of what I intend being from column 77 to 89. 
Alternatively if I replace the content of `Rng3` with hardcoded references it works just fine (i.e. `Rng3 = .Range("$AZ5662:$AZ5667,$BY$5662:$CJ$5667")`).

What is wrong?

Thank you very much!

Best regards,
Philip

```
Set Cht = .ChartObjects("Chart 14").Chart
Set Rng1 = .Range(Cells(5662, 52), Cells(5663 + Worksheets("Control").Range("F20"), 52))
Set Rng2 = .Range(Cells(5662, 77), Cells(5663 + Worksheets("Control").Range("F20"), 88))
Set Rng3 = .Range(Rng1, Rng2)
Cht.SetSourceData _
Source:=Rng3
Cht.PlotBy = xlRows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Range(Range1,Range2)`, it fetches the upper-left cell of `Range1`, and the lower-right cell of `Range2` to build a range.

Therefore the result of your Rng3 is a square starts from `Cells(5662,52)` and ends at `Cells(5663+X,88)`, which is not you wanted.

You can try another method called `Union( Rng1 , Rng2 , .... )`

It will store all the boundaries of each Range object given, so it can be several separated areas, or even an odd shape such as a heart or something :P

Comment: Thank you, using Union(rng1,rng2) solved the problem! :)